# Converting a for loop to a while loop with this "while (songInfo != null)"

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

```
public static void main(){
    String songInfo = MediaFile.readString();
    //System.out.println(MediaFile.readString());

    for (int x=10; x>0; x--){
        System.out.println(MediaFile.readString());
    }

    MediaFile.saveAndClose();
}
```

I need to convert the above for loop to a while loop using the condition

```
while (songInfo != null)
```

Comment: a while loop will iterate over it until the condition inside de while is not true... what did you tried?

Comment: Well, okay, give it a try. Show us your attempt if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the trouble is, but it sounds like you're looking for this:

```
while (songInfo != null) {
    System.out.println(songInfo);
    songInfo = MediaFile.readString();
}
```